# Compare string with CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a String (for example "Test") and I also have a few strings which are stored in CoreData. Now I'd like to check if the string "Test" also exists in CoreData. So I simply want to compare all strings which are saved in CoreData with the string "Test".

Does someone of you know how to do this in Swift?

Comment: Have you read about fetch requests in the Core Data programming guide?

Comment: So you want to fetch all stings that match "Test"? If so, use NSpredicates! So for example fetchRequest.predicate = NSpredicate("NAME_OF_ATTRIBUTE = Test")

Comment: Exactly. I'd like to check if there's an string which matches "Test". How can I do this in an if-statement (if there's an string which is equal to "Test I'd like to run some code")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any one-line solution, however you can:

- Fetch with predicate
- See if the returned array is empty (it doesn't exist in core data) or not (element exists).

---

```
var request : NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Core_Data_Entity");
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "Property_name = %@", @"Test")
var results : [NSManagedObject] = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as [Core_Data_Entity]
 if (results.count > 0) {
     //Element exists
 }
 else {
     //Doesn't exist
 }
```

Comment: I get the following error: `Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments` in this line of code `var results : [NSManagedObject] = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil) as [NSManagedObject]`. That's the only error I get. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Should be `format: "(property_name = 'Test'")` or `(format:"property_name = %@", "Test")`

Comment: @Mundi Ah yes, I never actually compare to something hard-coded so I didn't know :)